# Meteor - Template Level Subscription Not loading data

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have three subscriptions that I require for this one particular page.  Two of the three template level subscriptions are working perfectly and the third is not and is hanging the page up.  No errors are being thrown at all either in the console or in the server window.  I have several other pages with template level subscriptions that do not have any issues, for the life of me I can't figure out what I have done wrong here.

What I have is as follows:

```
Template.billingBoardTemplate.onCreated(function(){

  var self = this;

  // dynamic subscribes go here
  self.autorun(function(){
      // loading the collections we will need for this page
      self.subscribe('companyProfile');
      self.subscribe('trips', companyCode.get(), 'subscribeBillingBoard');
      self.subscribe('customers', companyCode.get(), 'subscribeBillingBoard', billingCustomerId.get() );

  });
});
```

the two that work are the trips and customers and the companyProfile one is not.  .  Below is the publish setups on the server.

```
Meteor.publish("companyProfile", function () {
if (this.userId){
    return companyProfileColl.find();
};
});

Meteor.publish("trips", function (companyCode, tripsSearchType) {
if (this.userId){
    if(tripsSearchType === "subscribeAll"){ // old method of subscribing
        return tripsColl.find({companyCode: companyCode});
    }

    if(tripsSearchType === "subscribeBillingBoard"){ // subscribing to trips and fields required for the billing board.
        return tripsColl.find({companyCode: companyCode, tripOverAllStatus: "Delivered"}, {fields: {
            tripNumberText: 1,
            companyCode: 1,
            customerName: 1,
            orderLoadNum: 1,
            orderTotalCharges: 1,
            orderCurrency: 1,
            custID: 1,
            orderExtraCharges: 1,
            orderGSTTotal: 1,
            orderPSTTotal: 1,
            orderTAXTotal: 1,
            loadConfUploadPath: 1,
            PODDocsPath: 1,
            "orderPickups.Customer": 1,
            "orderPickups.City": 1,
            "orderPickups.State": 1,
            "orderDeliveries.Customer": 1,
            "orderDeliveries.City": 1,
            "orderDeliveries.State": 1,
            "orderDispatch.stopPuDate": 1,
            "orderDispatch.stopDelDate": 1,
            "orderDispatch.truckNumText": 1,
            "orderDispatch.driverName": 1,
            "orderDispatch.carrierName": 1,
            "orderDispatch.trailerNumText": 1
        }});
    }
};
});

Meteor.publish("customers", function (companyCode, customersSearchType, customerId) {
if (this.userId){
    if(customersSearchType === "subscribeAll"){ // the old method to return all records.
        return customersColl.find({companyCode: companyCode});
    }


    if(customersSearchType === "subscribeReceivables"){ // receivables module, only need customer name and id
        return customersColl.find({companyCode: companyCode}, {fields: {customerName: 1}});
    }

    if(customersSearchType === "subscribeBillingBoard"){ // billing module module,only pulling one record so pulling all of it
        return customersColl.find({companyCode: companyCode, _id: customerId});
    }
};
});
```

Not the funny thing here is that If I just do a straight Meteor.subscribe outside of any functions or anything then the collection loads.  This has been driving me nuts for a couple hours as I can't see where I have done anything different the other subscribes that I have done on this and many other pages.

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to debug on server nad client:
First - check it's publication return somethng `console.log(companyProfileColl.find().fetch());`

Second - on the client - in dev console the same.

Comment: As I said in my question when I move the subscribe out of the autorun and change it to the meteor.subscribe then it works. There should be no reason it shouldn't work with self.subscribe in the autorun.

Comment: I also have Mongol installed so I can see everything that is loading for subscriptions.

Comment: Comment out all the code in that subscription and just return `this.ready()`.  Does stop the hanging?  If so, we can move further...

Comment: On their server side or the client subscribe side? And of course it will now have to wait as the power just went out here lol

Comment: Btw, why do you need "self.subscribe('companyProfile');" inside autorun? It doesn't depend on any  of variables.

Comment: It will I stripped out the reactive code to even try to get it to work.